# Switching between JFileChooser and FileDialog

Tags: java

I want to use JFileChooser for Windows and FileDialog for Macs in my Java app. I have it already written in JFileChooser, do I need to completely rewrite it to handle the case for Macs (i.e check if the current OS is Mac and reimplement everything using FileDialog) or is there a easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, you have to reimplement everything.

Long answer: you could try to add an additional abstraction layer on top of everything, e.g. something like `MyOpenDialog` and `MySaveDialog`. These classes decide upon the OS whether to use `JFileChooser` or `FileDialog`, so you still have to implement it once. But only once, and if you need it in multiple places in your application, you can just use your own classes.

Be aware that FileDialog does not offer all the features of JFileChooser, e.g. offering the user a list of file formats to choose from (`FileFilter`) is only available for `JFileChooser`.